# Unable to move the model after generating a rig

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, rigify

I am new to Blender, still trying the terms and how everything works.

I have finally placed the bones in a human model, and i am able to move the limbs freely.

[image]

The issue is that whenever I generate a rig (from what i've heard it gives you more control over the movement), I am not able to move the model anymore at all. All I can do is change the placement of all the arrows and circles that appear around my model, but it's completely stuck...frozen you could say.

[image]

This is me trying to move everything around in pose mode once I generated the rig.

I am not sure if it's just an issue of me not using the generated rig properly, or if I did something else wrong. Could someone please help me regarding this?

[image]

Comment: Can you [share](https://blend-exchange.com/) your .blend file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=qmsbWaA2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qmsbWaA2/)

Comment: Quite a few errors there I'm afraid. The scale hasn't been applied to either the armature or the model and the origins aren't in the same place. Also the bones from the spine to the top of the head should be perfectly aligned in front view. I suggest you follow Dikko 3D's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9q5I3cyYS2Y) on setting up rigify from start to finish.

Comment: @Mister Hyuna: A rig is **mesh parented to bones** so that repositioning bones you affect the mesh, which is the top image. And **rigify addon**, the bottom image, is used for amination and video making and may require the use of "all those arrows and circles" **instead** of bone repositioning. This could explain why your mesh stands still. I never used rigify so it's my guess and I suggest some reading on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a mesh for so-called "metarig" which consists of this set of bones:

[image]

This set of bones are temporary, and should not be used in armature deform

In same time, proper bones are (They have DEF at the beginning, to indicate that this bones used to deform mesh):

[image]

I think that you expect that *Rig* will move *Metarig* and *Metarig* will move mesh. I don't understand where you may found this idea. Metarig is used only for generating Rig, just to show Blender there all joins are located. After generating rig, metarig may be removed. So that your work to attach mesh to metarig completely useless, you have to set up armature deform directly to generated rig.